# mqsicreatebar "cannot be added to the BAR file because it does not contain any input nodes"

Tags: messagebroker

I'm using Websphere Message Broker Toolkit 7 and am trying to create an automated bar build.

whilst running the following command I'm getting the following error:

```
mqsicreatebar -data C:\temp -b test.bar -cleanBuild-p "CDC Adaptor" -o "C:\temp\UpdateQueryTime.msgflow"

ERROR: Resource UpdateQueryTime.msgflow cannot be added to the BAR file because it does not contain any input nodes.
```

I've seen this mentioned elsewhere however I've not yet found a solution. I can see that this flow contains an Input Terminal node.

Regards,

Sapatos

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an input node besides the one named "Input node" inside the group "Construction"? If not, you must.

Each top level flow (as opposed to sub-flows) requires an input node that is able to start its execution, allocating the execution instance to a thread in the Execution Group process. Examples of nodes able to do that are: MQInput, SOAPInput, HTTPInput and JMSInput nodes. The top level flow could also be deployed if it contains at least one sub-flow with one of the aforementioned nodes.

Regards

-Shrein